# How can I force the IP address & hostname to only be exposed as example.com on a Tomcat Server?

Tags: dns, webserver, url

I have a web server which is running on CentOS 6 on top of Tomcat7. Everything works fine, however, there are many ways that users can access the server.

For instance:

- IP Address
- `example.com`
- `www.example.com`

These addresses are all accessible via a browser. However I'd like to configure the server so that when IP address or `www.example.com` is accessed, it would point to `example.com.

> Example  
> IP Address, xxx.xx.xx.xx ► example.com  
> www.example.com
>   ► example.com

What is the easiest way to achieve this? Is DNS required to configure this on server?

Comment: I believe you asked this yesterday and it got closed. I've cleaned up your question but it's a bit off topic for this site, however I can try and help.

Comment: Yes, I was. I'm new to linux and learning, sorry for previous  unclear question. Thanks your help. You are the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really little you can do to stop this. Your best bet is going to be to put a set of rewrite rules in place within Tomcat so that when the various URLs or IP addresses are accessed they redirect or rewrite the accessing URL accordingly so that it's domain.com.

#### Frontend web server

Often times people will deploy a Tomcat or Jetty server with a web server sitting in front to help facilitate this. Where I work we use Nginx to do exactly this. You're essentially proxying the Tomcat server as a slave behind it. Deploying it this way allows for the Tomcat server to be "protected" so that it's only accessed in the manner which you want, since only the URLs that are exposed on the web server in front of it is accessible to the end users.

You can read more about this deployment model here:

- [Load Balancing Apache Tomcat with Nginx](http://java.dzone.com/articles/load-balancing-apache-tomcat)

Nginx is just one type of web browser, you could just as easily use Apache or something else to provide the frontend layer.

#### Rewriting with just Tomcat

The other approach is to use a module such as this one, [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), which can perform the URL rewriting within Tomcat itself. This approach is similar to using [Apache's mod_rewrite](http://devtidbits.com/2011/11/28/tuckey-urlrewrite-how-to/) module to cleanup and redirect incoming URLs.

There's a decent tutorial on how to create rules for UrlRewriteFilter, titled: [Tuckey URLRewrite How-To](http://devtidbits.com/2011/11/28/tuckey-urlrewrite-how-to/).

Comment: Thanks for your info and good explanation. I've succeeded to setup by using Nginx, the configuration is much more easier than mod_jk does.

Comment: @Alan - yes I used to use mod_jk too, no more.

Comment: Many thanks your comment :) I used to spend lot of time for googling mod_jk as well, finally got no results and confused.